# Compare Two Large JSON array

Tags: java, json, gson, comparator, large-data

I have two directories "A" and "B", each directory contains textfiles containing jsonarray of jsonobjects.
Need to compare jsonobjects in directory a with b and figure out which object is added,updated,deleted.
I cant load all jsonobjects since it will consume all the memory allocated hence i need to execute in batchwise.

kindly suggest a efficient method to achive this .
Thanks in advance
sample json array in each textfile. Each object has a unique key

```
[
   {
      name:x,
      uniqueId:1
   },
   {
     name:y,
     uniqueId:2
   }
]
```

I tried the brute force method.

Comment: That's very little context for a very big question.

Comment: Iterate through the files and the arrays in both directories and compare them.

Comment: Do you really have to diff the JSON data? It would probably be way easier to simply diff the JSON string content of the files. Also, adding to what @shmosel wrote, there are multiple open questions, such as (1) should the order of property names be considered (e.g. first `name` or first `uniqueId`), (2) should the order in the array be considered, e.g. if an entry is moved from index 0 to 5, is it then _removed_ + _added_ (or some combinations of _updated_), or should the array be considered identical?